# SwiftUI horizontal alignment from center to the right

Tags: layout, swiftui, hstack

I am trying to align a dynamic collection (ie of varying count) of views to the right of a centered view, without moving the center view from its original, center position.

For example, the center view is `Text("12")` and the views to the right are `[Text("+3"), Text("+10"), Text("-1")]` so I want the views to the right of `12` be displayed to its right, while `12` is centered horizontally on the screen:

`|                    12  +3 +10 -1          |`

If I try using an `HStack` the `12` will move away from center.  Is there a view modifier I can use?  ex. `Text("12").alignToRight(...)`

This solution aligns the collection to the left of the right edge of the screen, but that's not the same thing.

```
ZStack {
  Text("12")

  HStack(spacing: 4) {
    Spacer()
    Text("+3")
    Text("+10")
    Text("-1")
  }
}
```

I would prefer not to have to duplicate the `HStack` on the left side and then make it disappear so as to balance the `HStack` on the right (that is a ridiculous way of creating a layout, plus the example I'm providing here is simple, in actuality I have to use a `ForEach` over the dynamic collection), ie

```
HStack {

  Spacer()

  HStack(spacing: 4) {
    Spacer()
    Text("+3")
    Text("+10")
    Text("-1")
  }
  .opacity(0)

  Text("12")

  HStack(spacing: 4) {
    Spacer()
    Text("+3")
    Text("+10")
    Text("-1")
  }

  Spacer()

}
```

Using something like `Text("12").overlay(myCollectionView.offset(x: 16)` is also winging it, as the font size of the center text will vary, and so I'd have to guess and adjust the offset manually as well -- I'd rather have a padding between the two views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is possible approach based on alignment guides.

**Update: Xcode 14 / iOS 16 - still valid**

Tested with Xcode 11.3 / iOS 13.3.

[image: demo]

Define custom alignment

```
extension HorizontalAlignment {
   private enum HCenterAlignment: AlignmentID {
      static func defaultValue(in dimensions: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
         return dimensions[HorizontalAlignment.center]
      }
   }
   static let hCenterred = HorizontalAlignment(HCenterAlignment.self)
}
```

align needed element of internal `HStack` to external `VStack` using custom alignment guide

```
struct TestRightCenterred: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .hCenterred) {
            HStack(spacing: 4) {
                Text("12").border(Color.red) // << just for test
                    .alignmentGuide(.hCenterred, computeValue: { $0.width / 2.0 })
                Text("+3")
                Text("+10")
                Text("-1")
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .hCenterred, vertical: .center))
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very complicated solution to what should be an easy problem to solve -- not your fault, SwiftUI's fault.  I was hoping for a view modifier -- I think SwiftUI still needs some improvements.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with same problem and come with this solution

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 4) {
            HStack {               //HStack1
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
            }
            
            Text("12")
            
            HStack(spacing: 4) {   //HStack2
                Text("+3")
                Text("+10")
                Text("-1")
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code cause "HStack1" and "HStack2" have same width, I got this understanding from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62801621)

Two Spacers in Hstack1 are needed because one is ignored without other content (can be changed on empty Text("") for example, but I prefer Spacer)